# PHP parse_ini_file() echos contents to end user

Tags: php, ini

I've come across something seemingly weird when parsing an INI file with PHP. When calling `parse_ini_file()`, it echos the entire contents of the file to the end user.

INI File:

```
; Store database connection info here

[database]
host = "localhost"
dbname = "dbname"
username = "username"
password = "password"
```

PHP Code that parses INI File

`$settings = parse_ini_file('/path/to/ini/file.ini');
 echo $settings['dbname'];`

What the user sees:

`; Store database connection info here [database] host = "localhost" dbname = "dbname" username = "username" password = "password"dbname`

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this error, and have tried the examples from [PHP:parse_ini_file() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

I have also tried several variations on error reporting to see if that was causing the issue, but no luck!

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had a routine that was including files from the directory the INI was located, so it was output to the browser because it isn't proper PHP.